# boxplots from SPSS and Matlab show different outliers and percentiles

Tags: matlab, boxplot, spss

I encountered the below problem while trying to check my ANOVA data for outliers with MATLAB. By chance I also did it in SPSS and noticed the below weird thing:

I have a vector with 5 data points (for simplicity).

```
1.1648    0.4254    0.6796    0.5627    0.6904
```

I then use the Matlab boxplot command, i.e. boxplot(test) and get this:

[image: this]

looks reasonable.

I then copy the same vector into SPSS (I swear it's the same). I choose 'explore' from the analyze> descriptive stats menu. While I don't think it makes a difference in this case, I choose (from the plots option): boxplots: dependents together. Then I hit OK and get this:

[image: this]

There are two things that seem weird to me here:

1. The 3rd quartile appears to be larger in Matlab (above 0.8) whereas it is <0.8 in SPSS
2. Matlab doesn't seem to think there is an outlier. As far as I understand the documentation on "boxplot" in Matlab, outliers are, by default, defined as more than 1.5 times the interquartile range away from the 1st or 3rd quartile. This definition is the same in SPSS as far as I can gather.

I'm probably doing something wrong somewhere but can't figure out where. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: It seems to me that the MATLAB plot is wrong. Their computation of the 75th percentile of wonky. If you have 5 values, you directly have the 25, 50 and 75th percentiles. Those are the three values used to draw the box. How does MATLAB get 0.8?

Comment: good point...  it's probably to do with how the two programs deal with the (admittedly not very sensible) task of assigning percentiles to a group of 5 datapoints. That would explain why the two programmes agree with higher n number. Matlab also returns 0.8 if I type prctile(test,75)

Comment: I think that's a bug. Please submit that to The MathWorks.

Comment: ok will do, thanks for the help.....

Comment: I've looked around online for "how to compute percentiles", and found most tutorial-type resources to be wrong! They propose to take element `round(p*N)` after sorting, which is obviously wrong because if `p=0` this leads to an element that doesn't exist (presuming 1-based indexing). The correct thing is to take element `round(p*(N-1))+1`. But it seems, from what you say, that the MATLAB statistics toolbox uses the wrong equation? They're computing the 75th percentile as `0.75*5`, which falls between elements, and so they average elements 4 and 5!